# Can't read from serial port with socat and rawer option

Tags: socat

I'm trying to use socat to read data from a serial port; however, it doesn't appear to read from the port correctly when passed the `rawer` option.

If I read from the port with either `socat /dev/ttyTHS1,b9600 -` or `socat /dev/ttyTHS1,b9600,raw -` I see the expected data, but when I run `socat /dev/ttyTHS1,b9600,rawer -` I get no output.

I'm running this on Ubuntu 18.04 on an aarch64 processor with kernel version 4.9.140. I've tried with the "stock" socat from apt (1.7.3.2-2ubuntu2) and also socat version 1.7.4.1 that I built from source.

One thing I noticed is that when I run socat in a working configuration (e.g. with the `raw` option) and then examine the serial port with `stty -F /dev/ttyTHS1` it looks like

```
speed 9600 baud; line = 0;
min = 1; time = 0;
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost
-isig -icanon
```

whereas when socat is run with the `rawer` option it looks like:

```
speed 0 baud; line = 0;
min = 1; time = 0;
-cread
-brkint -icrnl -imaxbel
-opost -onlcr
-isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke
```

and when the same command is run with the `rawer` option on a different platform (socat 1.7.3.2-2ubuntu2, on Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64, 5.4.0-84-generic, opening a USB-serial device) the `speed` appears to populate correctly.

Is there a reason why `rawer` would not work as I'm using it?

Comment: I'm sure I had problems with rawer also in a version of socat in the past. Try just replacing it with the equivalent `raw,echo=0`.

Comment: Had a similar, maybe same, problem on a Debian 11-ish system. Details documented in https://github.com/dosemu2/dosemu2/discussions/1738

Comment: @ecm I just had a look at the latest [sources](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/). The code is in `xio-termios.c` where `case OPT_TERMIOS_RAWER` sets the termios `c_cflag = CS8`. This clears `CREAD`, which stops any input being received! It also clears stop bits and parity and modem bits; I really don't see why it is doing this at all. rawer was introduced in version 1.7.3.0.